# showing error [erorr code : ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED] while clicking on get direction button to to get goole map location

Tags: wordpress, web-applications, webview, android-webview, cleartext

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV5Hd.jpg)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PolGF.jpg)

We have WebApp our website trough the wordpress. we converted our website via app my site. when we click on the map to get diraction then it showing error. map work fine while browsering web and ios app. we are just facing problem while getting direction via android app. erorr code : ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED

we try to get help from google map api support & app my site support. but still not issue solved.
if anyone have idea about it please help. thanks and appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest under the application tag put the following code.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Then in your res folder create a folder named xml then create an xml file name it network_security_config.xml and add the following code inside.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
   <trust-anchors>
    <certificates src="system" />
   </trust-anchors>
  </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```